# Generate Regex with special characters and brackets

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex for this text `*[Failure] : Automation Failure, Reason - Unable to find Watch Live button on title detail page*`, I want to extract anything between `*[Failure] :` and `*`. I tried coming up with `\*\[Failure][ :,-,-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\*` but this does not work.

In my case desired output is `Automation Failure, Reason - Unable to find Watch Live button on title detail page`

Comment: You only escaped the first `*` and `[` but you'll want to escape the closing `]` as well. You're also looking to match spaces in the final bit, not just letters.

Comment: I added space, and have towards end for last *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to get everything between the `'*[Failure] :'` and the `'*'`, you can use a lookbehind and a lookahead to make the regex:

```regex
(?<=\*\[Failure] : ).*(?=\*)
```

- `(?<=\*\[Failure] : )` looks behind for `'*[Failure] :'`
- `(?=\*)` looks ahead for a `'*'`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some essential characters in the 2 character classes that you use to span the match till `*`, and to only get the part in between you can use a capture group or else you will have the full match only.

```
\*\[Failure][ :,-]+([a-zA-Z0-9, -]+)\*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IclxRR/1)